# cross compiling using windows bash for raspberry pi

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, symlink, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to cross compile `qt` for raspberry pi on Windows 10. I have done this before for linux and I thought I could use the Windows bash sub-system to replicate the process.

The problem I am having is that my raspberry pi root image is an `ext4` file system. Windows bash sub-system only allows one to mount NTFS based file systems.

What could I do to work around this? I could try to copy my raspberry pi file as is to a windows folder but the symlinks seem to get messed up (plus, I am not sure if that would work anyway).

Does anyone know how to work around this? Basically I would like to have a raspberry pi file system image mounted and accessible from the Windows bash subsystem.

Comment: Isn't the output of compiling Qt essentially just a bunch of headers and libraries? Can you control where (to which directory) the output is sent? If you can, then I would have thought that using `tar` to bundle the files together would preserve symbolic links and attributes. I guess the "approved" way to do this would be to turn you build into `apk` file or something of that nature, that you can install directly on the Pi; but that sounds like a lot of work.

Comment: @Kevin Boone It's the raspberry pi file system that I am having trouble mounting. What I would like to do is build Qt on my windows box using the bash subsystem for the pi. For this, I need to mount the pi filesystem for access to the libs and this is an ext4 based FS. This is where I am having issues.

Comment: So the problem is that you don't have a properly-populated environment to build for the Pi? I though you had that set up, and were struggling to get the output of the build process _to_ the Pi; but I guess I misunderstood. When I do this stuff for Android, I just make a big tarball of the appropriate 'lib'and 'usr' directories on an Android device, and unpack the whole lot in the sysroot of my cross-compiler. However, I don't know anything about the tools you're using to build Qt with, so that could be completely inappropriate.

Comment: Maybe you can try cygwin to copy from Ext4 to NTFS, it has a pretty good support of symlink and you can confiure it to use native NTFS symlink (yes you can do symlink with NTFS just as you can with ext4, but the support is poor and on Windows there are some required privileges). Also did you update to Windows 10 1709 ? It is just out and has some big updates for Bash (I don't know if it will solve your issues though). See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/10/11/whats-new-in-wsl-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update/

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Yes, I will see what happens with the Windows updates.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a project called Ext2Fsd (http://www.ext2fsd.com/) which can mount Ext2/Ext3/Ext4 on Windows. I assume that the windows Bash can reach any partition with the right drivers. People have questioned the quality of such a driver but it is certainly a possibility.

Another possibility is to move to another way of deployment. One I can think of is using rsync to push the binaries to a running raspberry pi.

Comment: Yeah, there is no problem with mounting on Windows but the bloody bash cannot see it...